# Http get service not able to assign result to variable

Tags: angular, http

Using the following service to set result to this.temp, console log shows the result when inside the subscribe, but returns undefined when outside.

```
   1) this.http.get('../../assets/students.json').subscribe((data)=>{
   2)   this.temp = data;
   3)   console.log(data);//shows result
   4)   console.log(this.temp);//shows result
   5) })
   6) console.log(this.temp);//undefined
```

but in the console line, 6 is outputted first and then 3 and 4

Comment: `get` is asynchronous, so order of calls is `1, 6, 2, 3, 4`. Edit: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Answer (score 1):

This happens as the http call in angular is implemented via observables which will evaluate asycn at a future point of time.Now if you want to do something with the data or this.temp you have to do it inside the subscribe call.